# Advise on using Cloudflare worker fetch javascript to mask url

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I think I'm close, I think my only problem is I am trying to load image.png and I am not sure how to encode or specify the content type.

I have site1 hosted on my cloudflare, and I want to use a worker to fetch/mask another site:
`*site1.com/*` > https://site2.com/images/image1.png while keeping the site1.com url in the browser.

I used their guide to craft this worker-
https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/fetch-html/

```
export default {
  async fetch(request) {
    const someHost = "https://storage.googleapis.com";
    const url = someHost + "/mybucket/image1.png";

    async function gatherResponse(response) {
      const { headers } = response;
      const contentType = headers.get("content-type") || "";
      if (contentType.includes("application/json")) {
        return JSON.stringify(await response.json());
      } else if (contentType.includes("application/text")) {
        return response.text();
      } else if (contentType.includes("text/html")) {
        return response.text();
      } else if (contentType.includes("image/x-png")) {
        return response.?????(); <<<<<<<<<<<< What goes here?????
      } else {
        return response.text();
      }
    }

    const init = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
      },
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, init);
    const results = await gatherResponse(response);
    return new Response(results, init);
  },
};
```

I made the above worker, routed `*.site1.com/*` to it, have an A record proxied thru CF A=192.0.2.1 but I get an error 522 timeout.

I think I need to add something different to handle an image response, but not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `response.arrayBuffer()` to receive the raw bytes of the response. This works for all content types, including text and JSON.

But note that if you are just passing the bytes through to the client, then you shouldn't be doing any of this. You can just do:

```
new Response(upstreamResponse.body, init);
```

This is much better than using your `gatherResponse` code because using `upstreamResponse.body` directly enables streaming. If you call `await response.text()` or `await response.arrayBuffer()`, the Worker will wait until the entire response from the server has been downloaded to the Worker's machine and loaded into memory, before it sends any of it back to the client. With `response.body`, you do not wait. Instead, the system streams bytes through to the client as they arrive.